# UIAlertController hides almost all UIKeyCommands

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, first-responder, uiresponder, uikeycommand

When a UIAlertController is presented, all UIKeyCommands from the responder chain are hidden besides the UITabBarController. The only key commands that work are: Escape, to dismiss the alert, and Return, to select the preferred action.

I want other commands to be available while the UIAlertController is shown, but this doesn't seem possible. I tried calling `resignFirstResponder()` on the alert controller and calling `becomeFirstResponder()` on another view controller, which does not work.

Is there a way to get around this limitation?

Comment: `UIAlertController`s are presented in a child view of the presenting controller's window. They are not added to the view hierarchy of the presenting view controller. I don't believe they are in the responder chain of your view controller hierarchy. So, the alert controller's `keyCommands` would not include those from your presenting view controller.